# CSS Head Nav and Dropdown Menu Alignment problem

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, alignment

I am working on a project for school and am trying to add a drop down menu to my head navigation. I am still pretty new to css but had fun playing with the styling to get an interesting alignment that would work with the vision I had for the page (this is part of a larger piece that I didn't include to keep it relevant to the question)

I wanted to create a right aligned menu that was set to the bottom of the head div. I got everything to work by using absolute positioning but now that I am trying to add a fancy multi level drop down menu things aren't working. I have tried combinations of inline block and relative and absolute positioning but the dropdown does not align correctly. It just bunches up at the bottom offset to the right.

When I try styling the nav bar like people do in tutorials it gets messed up when I remove the absolute positioning.

Is there a way to get the dropdown to work with the current method of styling? I don't have any hover effects or visibility yet because I can't even get it lined up! That part should be pretty straight forward for the dropdown and submenus.

*and probably more importantly* 
Is there a better way to accomplish this visual goal? (right-aligned at the bottom of the white div)

This is not a dynamic styling yet so you have to stretch the viewport for it to make sense.

```css
/*====================================MAIN=================================*/

body {
  background-color: #d5d3d5;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.flex_body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 20%);
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 800px;
}

.page_body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%);
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*=============================MAIN=NAVIGATION=================================*/

#header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -15px 18px -6px rgba(121, 104, 124, 0.678);
}

#headNAV ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 8px;
}

#headNAV ul li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;
}

#headNAV ul li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #8f85a1dc;
}

#headNAV ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 40px 10px 40px;
  margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #353138;
}

#headNAV ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #50328ddc;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 3px 1px #50328ddc;
}

#search_icon {
  max-width: 5%;
  max-height: 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
}

#headNAV ul li input {
  margin: 5px 35px 10px 35px;
}


/*======================myPage-Nav============================*/

#myPage_button:hover>#myPage {
  color: white;
}

#myPage_button {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#myPage {
  color: #50328ddc;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#dropdown-btn {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

#myPage-menu {
  margin: auto;
}

#headNAV ul li #myPage-menu li {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav id="headNAV">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
      <li><a id='myPage_button' href="#">My<span id='myPage'>Page</span><span id = "dropdown-btn" class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></a>
        <ul id="myPage-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Main Feed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..."></li>
      <li><a id="header_login" href="#">Login/SignUp</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you for any input!

- Kevin